# iptables and ip forwarding for failover

Tags: iptables, routing, netfilter, iptables-redirect

hi i have an ethernet nic interface with 4 additional virtual interfaces (failovers) all configured with public ip4 (IP-1 to IP-5) / netmask 255.255.255.255 / broadcast addr same as ip:

- eth0        -> IP-1

  - eth0:0   -> IP-2
  - eth0:1   -> IP-3
  - eth0:2   -> IP-4
  - eth0:3   -> IP-5

## The primary network interface

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address IP-1
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast IP-1

    post-up route add ISP-GW dev eth0
    post-up route add default gw ISP-GW
    post-up ip addr add 192.168.100.254/24 dev eth0

    post-down route del ISP-GW dev eth0
    post-down route del default gw ISP-GW
    post-down ip addr del 192.168.100.254/24 dev eth0
```

## failover 5

```
auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
        address IP-5
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast IP-5
```

## & bridge with local ip (IP-B) used by lxc

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        network 192.168.100.0
        address 192.168.100.100       # IP-B
        gateway 192.168.100.254       $ IP-GW
        broadcast 192.168.100.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

## test:

```
# ping lcx container 
#
    $ ping 192.168.100.1 
    PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms

# ping bridge br0
#
    $ ping 192.168.100.100   
    PING 192.168.100.100 (192.168.100.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms

# pink gatway / alias eth0 IP-1
#
    $ ping 192.168.100.254
    PING 192.168.100.254 (192.168.100.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
```

and i want now to route traffic from eth0 IP5 (eth0:3) <-> br0 IP-B   and other traffic to stay at eth0 how to set netfilter rules to achieve that ?

i know that i must add

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING
```

rules something like ?

```
# change public host IP-5 to private IP-B
# 
    $ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d IP-5 -j DNAT --to IP-B
#
# change private IP-B to public IP-5 use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE for static IP
# 
    $ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s IP-B -j SNAT --to IP-5
#
# force to send reply to gateway where IP-GW = 192.168.100.254/16
#
    $ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -s IP-GW -d IP-5 -j SNAT --to IP-B
```

and i have enabled also forwarding in sysctl

- lxc container is DEBIAN

  ```
  lxc.network.type = veth
  lxc.network.name = veth0
  lxc.network.flags = up
  lxc.network.link = br0
  lxc.network.veth.pair = veth0-sid
  lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.100.1/24
  lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.100.254
  ```

lxc container route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.254 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 veth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 veth0

veth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

- server is UBUNTU 15.10

  ```
  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default         ISP GW          0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
  default         192.168.100.254 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
  ISP GW          *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
  192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
  ```

when i ping IP-5 from outside tcpdump on br0 is not receiving any icmp 
do i need add some how gateway or static route ? what im doing wrong ?

```
# on lcx container 
#
    $ apt update 
    Err http://http.debian.net jessie Release.gpg                         
    Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'

     W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg     
       Could not resolve 'http.debian.net'


# on host :
#
     $ tcpdump -vi br0
     tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size  262144 bytes
     01:54:21.370892 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59200, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
       192.168.100.1.58916 > cdns.ovh.net.domain: 46783+ A? security.debian.org.local. (43)
     01:54:21.371049 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59201, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
       192.168.100.1.58916 > cdns.ovh.net.domain: 65501+ AAAA? security.debian.org.local. (43)

# host ping and  tcpdump 
#
    $ ping 192.168.100.1
    PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.118 ms

    $ tcpdump -vibr0  
    tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    02:07:47.168384 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 24937, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
        IP-5 > 192.168.100.1: ICMP echo request, id 5199, seq 1, length 64
    02:07:47.168460 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2157, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
        192.168.100.1 > IP-5: ICMP echo reply, id 5199, seq 1, length 64

    $ ping from outside IP-5  -> tcpdump on br0 no packet captured
```

## create routing table

```
# take my nic to world 
#    
     $ ip route add ISP-GW dev eth0 
     $ ip route add default via ISP-GW

     $ ip r
        default via ISP-GW dev eth0 
        ISP-GW dev eth0  scope link 

     $ ping IP-1 from outside  OK!


  # add bridge br0 route via gateway (alias of IP-1 = IP-GW) 
  #
      $ ip route add 192.168.100.100 via 192.168.100.254 

      $ ip r
         default via ISP-GW dev eth0 
         ISP-GW dev eth0  scope link 
         192.168.100.100 via 192.168.100.254 dev eth0
```

## one big question ?

should i receive icmp from IP-5 from outside if i set DNAT and bring down br0 ?